# pycharm can't reference global variable inside a function

Tags: python, pycharm

I defines a global variable in function.But PyCharm can't reference this global variable.
code like this:

```
a.py:
g_Handle = None
def Init():
    import mods
    global g_handle
    g_handle = mods.handle_class()

b.py:
import a
a.g_handle 
# PyCharm will reference 'g_handle' as None,
# but I want reference 'g_handle' as mods.handle_class
```

I try to add type for g_handle, but I don't want import mods directly in a.py

```
a.py:
g_handle =None # type: mods.handle_class
```

but this is not work.can't find mods
so I want to know how to let PyCharm can reference g_handle as mods.handle_class. 
Thank you.

Comment: it is like you are not defining `g_handle` in your file `a.py`. You should define it at the zero-indentation level.

Comment: yes . but I don't want assignt it at the zero-indentation level.Only want assign it in function. And I want PyCharm want reference g_handle as mods.handle_class.

Comment: a global variable by definition should be declared at the zero-indentation level. Otherwise, we are talking about local variables inside a function which are not accessible in other functions due scoping rules.

Comment: em.I'm sorry for didn't explain this question clearly.I have edited the question already.

Comment: it looks like you will have `g_handle` set as None until you call `Init`

Comment: yes.but I will call Init before use g_handle.because not want import mods in a.py.so I only can set g_handle as None

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's an element of the way you're asking your question, but it looks like you've got multiple problems here. The first is an import reference problem (or possibly using an import where a class would be more effective).

See, if you run the code only as you have described and provided, you would never get the correct answer that you seek because the Init function in a.py would never get called.

You need to have the intended global variable defined in some way in the global scope prior to being used like in your code.

The global statement merely tells the interpreter to link the values of the provided variable across all states. It does not define the variable in the outermost scope on its own.

Therefore, something like this (**EDIT: FIXED**):

```
a.py:
g_handle = False
def Init():
    import mods
    global g_handle
    g_handle = mods.handle_class()

b.py:
import a

a.Init()
a.g_handle
```

...should work to return what you're looking for.

If you could use a class instead of importing from another module, you could save yourself from trouble too:

```
import mods

class a():
    g_handle = False
    global g_handle

    def __init__(self, handle_class):
        g_handle = handle_class()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a(mods.handle_class).g_handle
```

Comment: but PyCharm can't reference a.g_handle as mods.handle_class alse, and no have smart code completion.I'm sorry for didn't explain this question clearly.

Comment: sorry I made a mistake in my code. it should work now. I changed g = False to g_handle = False